# Wordpress Conditional Display

Tags: wordpress, tags, conditional-statements

In WordPress, I want to display a button if the cart total amount is equal to or greater than $35.

```
<div class="xoo-cp-btns">
    <a class="xoo-cp-btn-vc xcp-btn" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>"><?php _e('View Cart','added-to-cart-popup-woocommerce'); ?></a>
    <a class="xoo-cp-btn-ch xcp-btn" href="<?php echo wc_get_checkout_url(); ?>"><?php _e('Checkout','added-to-cart-popup-woocommerce'); ?></a>
    <a class="xoo-cp-close xcp-btn" href="<?php echo apply_filters('xoo_cp_continue_shopping_url','#'); ?>"><?php _e('Continue Shopping','added-to-cart-popup-woocommerce'); ?></a>
</div>
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Are you using woocommerce plugins for product and cart system?

Comment: Yes @PrakashSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
<?php 
global $woocommerce;
$cart_total_amount = floatval( preg_replace( '#[^\d.]#', '', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() ) );
if($cart_total_amount >= 35)
{
    echo '<a href="#" class="btn">Test</a>';
}
  ?>
```

You can change the anchor URL, Class and text as well according to your requirement.